# Movie end credits software

Tags: windows, video

I am looking for a windows-based program that will help the user create basic end credits (black screen, white text, scrolling effect) of a movie. I am making a 3 minute movie and want to include ending credits.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're doing a movie then why don't just create credits using whatever software you're using to edit the video?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Windows Movie Maker

Download: http://windows.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-live/movie-maker#t1=overview

- Free
- Supports inserting a black screen with white text
- Supports inserting scrolling text